# What is the best way to run JavaScript in lockstep with a child process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization, pipe, child-process

### The Issue: (solution at Edit 2)

I am running JavaScript using NodeJS.

I have a child process which reads and writes to pipes. This is within a class called by other code. After I write to the child process pipe, I need to wait for an answer and then return the answer. What is the best way to accomplish this?

As far as I understand in JavaScript you are intended to use events, like `someStream.on('data', (data) => {...});` but that requires the entire JavaScript file(s) to be processed by Node before the event loop is checked. But in this case I need the output of a stream before finishing the execution of the script. I am aware this is not the intended way of using JavaScript, but I am modifying an existing package and cannot make changes in the interface.

I am aware of spawnSync/execSync but that is not a good solution because the output of the spawned process is required up to 10 000s of times, and the spawned program runs on the JVM.

**This is a simplified example of what I am trying to do:**

```
const {spawn} = require("child_process");

class Context {
    constructor() {
        this.program = spawn("/path/to/some/program", ["my", "arguments"]);
    }

    someMethod(string) {
        if (this.program.stdin.write(string + "\n") == null) {
            console.log("Program stdin overflow");
        }

        var result = /* Here I need the output of the program. */;
        if (result == "some output") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

### Edit 1

The NodeJS version is 8.12 which is old, but this cannot be changed.

### Edit 2

**Solved it.** I cheated by using `child_process.spawnSync()` on a small auxiliary C program whose sole purpose was to relay information from the child process by using a named pipe. That way information from a living child process obtained during synchronous code. Might also be possible to do busy wait using `fs.readSync()` on the named pipe, but wanted the blocking call.

Comment: When you say `pipe`...are you talking about sockets? Like `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`? For example from the terminal you can do `ls | grep asdf`, and I believe that basically "pipes" the `stdout` of the `ls` command to the `stdin` of the `grep` command. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. In this situations the file descriptors for stdin, stdout and stderr are represented as streams, which are members of the ChildProcess class in Node.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript/node is an event driven language, and you'll be happy to know that you can set up events based receiving stream data. That's how you would handle this, and it's something JavaScript does quite well.

As you mention in your reply comment, the ChildProces class has members for the  the standard  `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` streams of child processes. And streams have several events, one of which is `data`.

In practice it would look something like this:

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

const bash = spawn("/bin/sh", ["-c", `
  while true; do echo 'doing stuff'; sleep 1s; done
`]);

bash.stdout.on('data', d => {
  console.log(d.toString('utf8'));
});

bash.stderr.on('data', e => {
  console.log('err', e);
});
```

That's how you would receive communications from the child process. Of course sending information back to the child process can be done using the `stdin` pipe, only you'd do a `write` or `pipe` or something. Those don't need to be events, since JavaScript controls when they happen. So you just write the data when you need to.

Comment: Yes, this is the intended way of doing it, but the issue still remains that before the events from stdout/stderr are handled, the entire .js file(s) need to be run. The data needs to be extracted in the method, because the return value of the method is dependent on the child process. Also this does not answer the question of "What is the best way to run JavaScript in lockstep with child process?".

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what that means. Perhaps you can edit your question to make it more clear...there's clearly information missing that is needed. And for that matter you might think about adding in the `data` event information into your question. In your comment you make it sound as if you already knew that was the way to do it, but you didn't say anything about it in your question, which made it appear that was the thing you needed help with.